# Casting from System.Linq.EnumerableQuery to System.Data.Datatable (using Dynamic LINQ)

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamic, exception, casting

I'm trying to get the results from a Dynamic LINQ query into a DataTable. Trying to get the query directly into a DataTable gives me this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[DynamicClass1]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

My code is:

```
Dim query = tbl.AsEnumerable.AsQueryable.Select("new(it[""curr""] as Curry)")
Dim tbl As DataTable = query
```

Ive tried:

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = tbl.AsEnumerable.AsQueryable.Select("new(it[""curr""] as Curry)").Cast(Of DataRow)()
Dim tbl1 As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable
```

but that gives me:

> Unable to cast object of type 'DynamicClass1' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Public Shared Function ConvertIEnumerableToDataTableFromProperties(Of T)(ByVal list As IEnumerable(Of T)) As DataTable
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim fields() As PropertyInfo = GetType(T).GetProperties()
        For Each field As PropertyInfo In fields
            table.Columns.Add(field.Name, field.PropertyType)
        Next
        For Each item As T In list
            Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
            For Each field As PropertyInfo In fields
                row(field.Name) = field.GetValue(item)
            Next
            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        Return table
    End Function
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).